# Mysql- update mulitiple columns from select with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table and I need to update it using a select from another table.

What I had in mind:

```
UPDATE articles, 
    (SELECT  count(*) AS count FROM nots WHERE otherID=243 GROUP BY number) AS cnots 
SET articles.first=(SELECT count FROM cnots WHERE number=1),
    articles.second=(SELECT count FROM cnots WHERE number=2),
    articles.third=(SELECT count FROM cnots WHERE number=3)
WHERE articles.ID=243
```

The query throws an error "Table 'mydb.cnots' doesn't exist".

I can do it with 3 different selects,  but I don't want to, any ideas?

Comment: Why you are writing this (SELECT  count(*) AS count FROM nots WHERE otherID=243 GROUP BY number) AS cnots in Update any specific reason

Comment: I need to use those results for the Set operator. The ID will change every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT  count(*) AS count FROM nots WHERE otherID=243 GROUP BY number) AS cnots
```

Here this line should be as if there is a one table as cnots. this should be like this

```
(SELECT  count(*) FROM cnots WHERE otherID=243 GROUP BY number) AS cnots
```

Comment: But there aren't such a table, its a temp table im trying to update from. The real table is nots.

Answer (score 0):

how about that

->

```
UPDATE articles 
   SET articles.first=(SELECT cnots.count
                       FROM 
                      (SELECT  count(*) AS count 
                             FROM nots WHERE otherID=243 GROUP BY number) AS cnots
                                WHERE number=1)
```

.......

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM'.

you can't use 'FROM' when updating in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is the best solution I've found:

```
update articles, 
       (SELECT  sum(case when number = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS first,
                sum(case when number = 2 then 1 else 0 end) AS second,
                sum(case when number = 3 then 1 else 0 end) AS third
                FROM nots WHERE otherID=243 ) AS cnots 
       SET articles.first=cnots.first,
           articles.second=cnots.second,
           articles.third=cnots.third
       WHERE articles.ID=243
```